# Why am i getting seg. fault?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm starting with pointers, and I can't see the reason why I'm getting a segfault with this code. I guess I'm accessing the array the wrong way, so how should I access it?

```
const int MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL = 20;

typedef struct {
    string titulo;
    char genero;
    int puntaje;
} libro_t;

int main(){
    libro_t** libros = new libro_t*[MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL];
    int tope_libros = 0;

    libros[tope_libros]->titulo = "hola";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You create array of pointers. Each pointer points nowhere after creation. Then you try to access objects through them.

Comment: `libro_t *libros0; libros0->titulo = "hola";` <- why doesn't it work?

Comment: Seeing a `typedef struct` immediately puts the quality of your learning material into question. That is something you do in C, not in C++

Comment: Yes. I come from c and started with c++ yesterday. Im not focusing in structs now, im focusing in pointers.

Comment: Then don't do it. Don't do `typedef struct`, and definitely don't do `libro_t*[]`. That's a terrifying type. C++ is a language with high-level abstractions. As a beginner, you shouldn't even be touching raw pointers. `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, and references are the main tools of a modern C++ programmer. Your C knowledge may actually be counterproductive here, as C encourages a lot of practices that, in C++, are allowed but strongly discouraged.

Comment: Best practice is to use either `std::array<libro_t, MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL> libros;` or `std::vector<libro_t> libros(MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL);`. Stay away from `new[]` until you have a better grasp of proper memory management.

Comment: I appreciate your concerns about my " learning material ". I understand that this code might not be the best for practical reasons but my goal here is only understanding pointers. Im not allowed to use std::vector or any kind of templates. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: "<- why doesn't it work?" Why **should** it work? Hint: what happens if I write an address onto an envelope and mail it there, and there is *no actual building* at that address?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I see what i was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an array of pointers that don't point anywhere.  You are getting a segfault from trying to access invalid memory.  You need to create the individual objects that the pointers will point at, eg:

```
const int MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL = 20;

struct libro_t {
    string titulo;
    char genero;
    int puntaje;
};

int main(){
    libro_t** libros = new libro_t*[MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL; ++i) {
        libros[i] = new libro_t;
    }

    int tope_libros = 0;

    libros[tope_libros]->titulo = "hola";
    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL; ++i) {
        delete libros[i];
    }
    delete[] libros;

    return 0;
}
```

Though, you really have 1 level of indirection too many, and should drop one level of `*`, eg:

```
const int MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL = 20;

struct libro_t {
    string titulo;
    char genero;
    int puntaje;
};

int main(){
    libro_t* libros = new libro_t[MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL];
    int tope_libros = 0;

    libros[tope_libros].titulo = "hola";
    ...

    delete[] libro_t;
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, consider using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead, let them manage the memory for you, eg:

```
#include <vector> // or: <array>

const int MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL = 20;

struct libro_t {
    string titulo;
    char genero;
    int puntaje;
};

int main(){
    std::vector<libro_t> libros(MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL);
    // or: std::array<libro_t, MAXIMO_LIBROS_INICIAL> libros;

    int tope_libros = 0;

    libros[tope_libros].titulo = "hola";
    ...

    return 0;
}
```